# mod_rewrite not working for clean urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using wamp server for my projects and have stuck in making the urls clean

currently my url address is like this

```
http://localhost/BookProjectFinal/booksdetails.php?pid=8
```

I want to make it like this

```
http://localhost/BookProjectFinal/booksdetails/8
```

What I am using in my .htaccess file is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ booksdetails.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ booksdetails.php?pid=$1
```

But its not working its returning the whole url. What the problem with it? Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `RewriteLog` you surely use for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RewriteBase parameter will tell mod_rewrite from which directory to start matching.  This can be used for applications that live in subfolders of apache.  You may want to set it to /BookProjectFinal/ here.

Your regexp is looking to match a complete alphanumeric URL optionally followed by a slash, which I'm not sure is what you want.  Try something like:

```
RewriteRule bookdetails/([0-9]+) bookdetails.php?pid=$1
```

to match only the number.  Here's a test:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bookdetails/([0-9]+) bookdetails.php?a=b&pid=$1
```

Matches URLs of the form /bookdetails/8.  Use print_r($_GET) to sanity check in bookdetails.php

Comment: Updated the answer - you may need to add RewriteEngine On?

Comment: I got it working thanks all for the help. The thing i am doing wrong is providing <a href="bookdetails.php?id=myvariable"> so i changed it to just myvariable and all works fine